# Selenium - use session from current Chrome instance

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate some form filling for a web app. Users have to login to the application and then start filling up pages of forms. I have the following Python script using Selenium that can open a window to my application:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python\\Selenium\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.add_cookie()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("myurl/formpages")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.quit()
```

However, when Selenium starts the Chrome window, the user is not logged in. I want to bypass the need to log in every time.

On another Chrome window, I am already logged in as my test user. So whenever I go to the url on my Chrome window, I am already logged in and don't have to log in again.

Is there any way to pass this data into my Selenium script so that it uses the session currently on my existing Chrome instance, therefore not having to log in via the script?

Comment: Have you tried pulling the ***Cookies*** from the logged in instance of Chrome and adding them to the new instance of Chrome?

Comment: Are you sure about your code attempts **`Ie("C:\\...\\chromedriver.exe")`**

Answer (score 1):

Historically, this is not possible unfortunately (made frustrating by my agreement when I realize the effort it involves and for each browser!).

I've written code before that takes variables out of a CSV for username and password. This is bad because it's in plaintext but you can also hash the information if you like and handle that in your code.

So to recap, there are mediocre solutions, but no native way to handle this in selenium :(

Comment: So I would have to add the login logic to my script and login every time? Is there a reliable alternative or workaround that someone else might have made for this? I only need it to work on Chrome.

Comment: it's a good question, it seems like there ought to be a way. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bUUw0gPvQmM has some useful information about this.

however, to answer your question, your understanding is the same as mine. It's something that is a part of every runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium by default creates a temporary chrome profile each time you start a new instance and deletes that profile once you quit the instance. If you change the chrome options in selenium driver to use a custom chrome profile and and allow that profile to save cookies, you will be able to login without each time typing your login details etc.